# Помогите понять синтаксис C#

Tags: c#

Почему `A = Console.ReadLine();` объявляется так ?

И что это за команды `A = string.Concat(A.Select(B => (char)(char.ToLower(B) ^ char.ToUpper(B) ^ B)))`?

```
string A;
A = Console.ReadLine();
A = string.Concat(A.Select(B => (char)(char.ToLower(B) ^ char.ToUpper(B) ^ B)));
Console.WriteLine("Полученная строка " + A);Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: А может, того... по-старинке, книжку почитать?

Comment: читал ,я выписал какая команда ,что обозначает ,но там нету когда можно использовать такое объявление A = Console.ReadLine();. Но так же я знаю что это за команды char.ToLower(B) ^ char.ToUpper(B) ^ B) , но что обозначает (B) ^ B)

Comment: Да не объявление это, а вызов функции (точнее - метода объекта). ^ - xor

Comment: Метод `ReadLine()` возвращает значение - строку. Это значение присваивается переменной `A`.

Comment: Спасибо,Alexander Petrov.

Comment: Можно упростить: A = string.Concat(A.Select(B => char.IsLetter(B) ? (char)(B ^ 32) : B));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Почему объявляется так ?

Так захотел разработчик этого кода:

```
int i = 0;
```

и

```
int i;
i = 0;
```

- равнозначный код

> И что это за команды?

Начну изнутри

`char.ToLower(B) ^ char.ToUpper(B) ^ B` инвертирует регистр символа. `^` - побитовая операция XOR, двоичная арифметика.

```
XOR
0 ^ 0 = 0
1 ^ 0 = 1
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
```

То есть если провести операцию для двух одинаковых чисел, то получится 0. А если 0 с числом, то получится само число

```
123 ^ 123 = 0
0 ^ 234 = 234
```

тип `char` в C# неявно может быть преобразован в `int`, и получается код символа.

Если буква в верхнем регистре, то XOR самого символа с переводом его `.ToUpper()` в верхний регистр даст 0. То же самое с нижним регистром и `.ToLower()`

К пример код латинской буквы `A` 65, а код `a` 97, вот и получается одно из двух

```
97 ^ 65 ^ 97 = 65
97 ^ 65 ^ 65 = 97
```

вот и вся магия, дальше `(char)` - преобразование обратно в символ.

`A.Select(B => ...)` это **Linq** [операция выбора](https://professorweb.ru/my/LINQ/base/level2/2_2.php) символа B из строки А (плохие названия переменных, легко запутаться).

`string.Concat(...)` - склеивает полученные символы обратно в строку.

По сути это же самое можно записать в виде цикла

```
string text = Console.ReadLine();
string result = "";
foreach (char c in text)
{
    result += ((char)(char.ToLower(c) ^ char.ToUpper(c) ^ c)).ToString();
}
Console.WriteLine("Полученная строка " + result);
```

Будет работать точно так же.

Comment: Мало того, что равнозначный, так решарпер например будет настройчиво предлагать объединить их.